# MVC Replace Text with Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my MVC view, I would like to replace an instance of the text >>> with an image.

For example:

```
Model.Text  :  "3 >>> 4"
```

I want some way of doing:

```
@Helper.Replace(Model.Text)
```

In my view so that the text that is output is:

```
3 <img src="arrow.gif" /> 4
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `Model.Text` have raw user-input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@(new HtmlString(Model.Text.Replace(">>>", "<img src='arrow.gif' />")))
```

Comment: I also need arrow.gif to use Url.Content("~/Content/arrow.gif"), I couldn't figure out how to do that as well.